# How to remove ImageCache when we use SDImageCache?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to remove ImageCache when we use SDImageCache in ios?

when i use SDImageCache class then all images are store in my cache memory. so i cannot release it. it show previous image in imageview.

```
SDImageCache *imageCache = [SDImageCache sharedImageCache];[imageCache clearMemory];[imageCache clearDisk];[imageCache cleanDisk];
```

Comment: search for the cache saving duration in the code of sdimagecahce library and limit the duration to the time you want to have thew cahche of images in your app.

Comment: SDImageCache *imageCache = [SDImageCache sharedImageCache];
[imageCache clearMemory];
[imageCache clearDisk];
[imageCache cleanDisk];